# TypeError: firebaseApp.firestore is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
const db=firebaseApp.firestore();
export default db;
```

the error occurs in this line of code
Ive tried importing everything and every possible method but still the error shows up everytime.

the full code is

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
//import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import "firebase/firestore";
import 'firebase/auth';

// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: '',
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: ""
  });
  const db=firebaseApp.firestore();
  export default db;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are using Firebase Modular SDK `V9.0.0+` which has a completely new syntax. If you wish to use existing syntax, change your imports to `compat` version:

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/compat/firestore";
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
```

However I'd recommend [upgrading to Modular SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) syntax because has supports tree-shaking and will be lighter than existing version. Checkout this Firecast to learn more about new syntax for Firestore:

[Getting started with Cloud Firestore for Web](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BjtxPj6jRM8)