# Server Error TypeError: firebaseApp.firestore is not a function error

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Here is my code:

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.7.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
//import "firebase/firestore";
//import {firebase} from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';


const firebaseConfig = {

apiKey: "A*******************",

authDomain: "u*****.com",

projectId: "u******a",

storageBucket: "unl***********.com",

messagingSenderId: "5***********",

appId: "1:5************",

measurementId: "G-"

};

// Initialize Firebase


const firebaseApp =firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = firebaseApp.firestore();

export { db };
```

**Troubleshooting done so far:**

1.Tried importing "import * as firebase from "firebase/app" and import 'firebase/firestore';

2. re-installed npm.
3. deleted nodes and package-lock.json and reinstalled them.
4. Installed firebase and firestore.

[image: Error Image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: firebaseApp.firestore is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69395321/typeerror-firebaseapp-firestore-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

You are using **Firebase SDK version 9**, the way you import and initialize your Firebase SDK is for older version that's why you are receiving that error.

Use **Firebase version 8 or below** to still run your current code without any changes. You can change it in `package.json` or by running the command below:

```
npm install firebase@8.0.0 --save
```

the sample dependencies in **`package.json`**:

```
"dependencies": {
    "firebase": "8.0.0",
    "next": "11.1.2",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2"
}
```

But if you want to use the latest **Firebase version `9.0.0` and above** which is implementing **modular API** and you want to adapt the modular API. Use `compat` packages, in your case, it should be:

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
```

**Please [NOTE](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#about_the_compat_libraries)**:

> the `compat` libraries are a temporary solution that will be removed completely in a future major SDK version (**such as version 10 or version 11**). Your ultimate goal is to remove compat code and keep only version 9 modular-style code in your app.

Like [Dharmaraj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69396255/8753991), you should upgrade from version 8 to the modular Web SDK.

> However I'd recommend upgrading to Modular SDK syntax because has supports tree-shaking and will be lighter than existing version. Checkout this Firecast to learn more about new syntax for Firestore: [Getting started with Cloud Firestore for Web](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BjtxPj6jRM8)